# C# How to serialize/deserialize a string array as a series of named elements

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have referenced this question: [Using XmlSerializer with an array in the root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924221/using-xmlserializer-with-an-array-in-the-root-element)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Subscribers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SubscriberList>
    <Subscriber>
      <Email>test@somewhere.com</Email>
      <SubscriptionList>
        <Subscription>
          <Source>TFSBuildServiceHost.2013</Source>
        </Subscription>
        <Subscription>
          <TextContains>
            <string>ABC</string>
            <string>DEF</string>
            <string>XYZ</string>
          </TextContains>
        </Subscription>
      </SubscriptionList>
    </Subscriber>
  </SubscriberList>
</Subscribers>
```

This is what I want my XML to look like.  How can I change the code below to build it in this fashion.

```
        <Subscription>
            <TextContains>ABC</TextContains>
            <TextContains>DEF</TextContains>
            <TextContains>XYZ</TextContains>
        </Subscription>
```

This is my class definition to serialize:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization; 

namespace EventLog_Reporter
{
    public class Subscription
    {
        public string Source;
        public List<string> TextContains;
        public List<string> UCTextContains;
        public List<string> TextExcludes;
        public List<string> UCTextExcludes;
    }

    public class Subscriber
    {
        public string Group;
        public string Email;
        public List<Subscription> SubscriptionList; 
    }

    public class Subscribers 
    {
        public List<Subscriber> SubscriberList;
    }
}
```

This is my code to write out the serialized object to an XML file:

```
    public static void testSerialization()
    {
        Subscribers subscribers = new Subscribers();
        Subscription subscription1 = new Subscription();
        Subscription subscription2 = new Subscription();
        Subscriber subscriber1 = new Subscriber();

        subscription2.TextContains = new List<string>(); 
        subscription2.TextContains.Add("ABC"); 
        subscription2.TextContains.Add("DEF"); 
        subscription2.TextContains.Add("XYZ"); 

        subscription1.Source = "TFSBuildServiceHost.2013";

        subscriber1.Email = "test@somewhere.com";
        subscriber1.SubscriptionList = new List<Subscription>(); 
        subscriber1.SubscriptionList.Add(subscription1);
        subscriber1.SubscriptionList.Add(subscription2);

        subscribers.SubscriberList = new List<Subscriber>();
        subscribers.SubscriberList.Add(subscriber1);

        string strOutFilenameXMLSerializer = "xmlSerializerObjectTest1.xml"; 
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strOutFilenameXMLSerializer);
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(subscribers.GetType());
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, subscribers);
        sw.Close(); 

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to specify that your `List<string>` should be serialized without an outer wrapper element:

```
public class Subscription
{
    public string Source;
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> TextContains;
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> UCTextContains;
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> TextExcludes;
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> UCTextExcludes;
}
```

Doing so will cause the list to be serialized as a sequence of elements each having the same name as the list property being serialized, in this case `TextContains`.

If you had needed to override the element name, it can be specified in the attribute constructor:

```
    [XmlElement("Contains")]
    public List<string> TextContains;
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried that, but maybe I was making too many changes at once.