# Deserializing XML, where the root object is an array returns only a single element

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

I have an XML document that I am working with, which I am trying to deserialize into a class. Here are the classes I have been working with:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("list")]
public class ItemRoot
{
    public ItemRoot()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }
    [XmlElement("itemDefinition")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class Item
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("examine")]
    public string Examine { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("equipmentType")]
    public string EquipmentType { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("noted")]
    public bool Noted { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("noteable")]
    public bool Noteable { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("stackable")]
    public bool Stackable { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("parentId")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("notedId")]
    public int NotedId { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("members")]
    public bool Members { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("specialStorePrice")]
    public int SpecialStorePrice { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("generalStorePrice")]
    public int GeneralStorePrice { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("highAlcValue")]
    public int HighAlcValue { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("lowAlcValue")]
    public int LowAlcValue { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("bonus")]
    public List<int> Bonus { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[{Id}]{Name}";
    }
}
```

And here's a short excerpt of the XML file, containing one item in the array (the real file I use has more than one, just to be clear):

```
<list>
  <itemDefinition>
  <id>0</id>
  <name>Stack Overflow</name>
  <examine>Add coffee.</examine>
  <equipmentType>NONE</equipmentType>
  <noted>false</noted>
  <noteable>false</noteable>
  <stackable>false</stackable>
  <parentId>-1</parentId>
  <notedId>-1</notedId>
  <members>true</members>
  <specialStorePrice>0</specialStorePrice>
  <generalStorePrice>0</generalStorePrice>
  <highAlcValue>0</highAlcValue>
  <lowAlcValue>0</lowAlcValue>
  <bonus>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>0</int>
  </bonus>
</itemDefinition>
```

And here is my deserialization method:

```
            XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemRoot));
            _file.Position = 0;
            object file = reader.Deserialize(_file);
            Root = (ItemRoot)file;
            _file.Close();
```

I have tried looking into [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924221/using-xmlserializer-with-an-array-in-the-root-element) questions, however using those solutions yielded no results.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem from your question.  What do you mean by *where the root object is an array returns only a single element*?  A valid XML document must have one and only root element, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element.  Your XML is incomplete (fails validation at http://www.xmlvalidation.com/, e.g.) so could you please edit your question to give a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you have XML with multiple  **itemDefinition** sections and you want to deserialize that to a **List** of **itemDefinition**(s)....

Try this

Usings.....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Classes.....

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "bonus")]
public class Bonus
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "int")]
    public List<string> Int { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "itemDefinition")]
public class ItemDefinition
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "examine")]
    public string Examine { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "equipmentType")]
    public string EquipmentType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "noted")]
    public string Noted { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "noteable")]
    public string Noteable { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "stackable")]
    public string Stackable { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "parentId")]
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "notedId")]
    public string NotedId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "members")]
    public string Members { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "specialStorePrice")]
    public string SpecialStorePrice { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "generalStorePrice")]
    public string GeneralStorePrice { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "highAlcValue")]
    public string HighAlcValue { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "lowAlcValue")]
    public string LowAlcValue { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "bonus")]
    public Bonus Bonus { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "list")]
public class List
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "itemDefinition")]
    public List<ItemDefinition> ItemDefinition { get; set; }
}
```

code.....

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string strXML = File.ReadAllText("xml.xml");
        byte[] bufXML = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML);
        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(bufXML);

        // Deserialize to object
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List));
        try
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ms1))
            {
                List deserializedXML = (List)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }// put a break point here and mouse-over deserializedXML….
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I saved\read your XML from a file called xml.xml in the application build folder.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Items node underneath the list element, and then put the item nodes underneath it.  If you cannot change the xml then try serializing as an array or list directly instead of as an object that contains a list.

Comment: Yes, I cannot change the XML. Using just the array doesn't seem to work, serialization results with the `<list>` element being changed to an `<ArrayOfItem>` element, and `<itemDefitinion>` to `<Item>`, the class name. I have `[XmlElement("list")]` above my list declaration, but I've also tried `[XmlArray("list"), XmlArrayItem("itemDefinition")` which didn't yield any different results. Needless to say the deserialization simply throws an exception.

Comment: The trick in this case is to remove the root class altogether, such as:XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item[]));
            _file.Position = 0;
            object file = reader.Deserialize(_file);
            Root = (Item[])file;
            _file.Close();