# How to use array with XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm making some test to use it.

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ma>233</ma>
    <ma>2333</ma>
</test>
```

I have this class to deserialize it:

```
[Serializable]
public class test
{
    public string ma { get; set; }
}
```

It does contains the first element. Now I want both so I try setting an array

```
[Serializable]
public class test
{
    public string[] ma { get; set; }
}
```

However setting an array I have now 0 result in ma variable, while I at least have the first one when it is not an array.

I found this answer [Using XmlSerializer with an array in the root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924221/using-xmlserializer-with-an-array-in-the-root-element), but he used another logic... I'd like to keep using `[Serializable]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indicate that the array doesn't have a separate xml element to wrap its items, but that the array items appear directly under the `<test>` element:

```
public class test
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string[] ma { get; set; }
}
```

PS. sometimes it's hard to get the mapping right - I usually fill in a class with test data and *serilalize* it, examining what `XmlSerializer` makes of that usually clears up what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you found provides the information you need.
[Serializable] doesn't help you because it isn't used by XmlSerializer, see [Why doesn't the XmlSerializer need the type to be marked [Serializable]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392431/why-doesnt-the-xmlserializer-need-the-type-to-be-marked-serializable)